# Blocking a p:commandButton displayed on a p:confirmDialog in addition to displaying a dynamic message on the dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to block a `<p:commandButton>` which is displayed on a `<p:confirmDialog>` as follows.

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDeleteDialog" widgetVar="confirmDelete" message="Message" closeOnEscape="true" appendTo="@(body)" closable="true">
    <p:blockUI block="confirm" widgetVar="blockUI">
        <h:outputText value="Demo"/>
    </p:blockUI>

    <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes" onstart="PF('blockUI').show()" oncomplete="PF('blockUI').hide();"/> <!--Use PF('confirmDelete').hide() to dismiss the dialog.-->
    <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" onclick="PF('confirmDelete').hide()" type="button" />               
</p:confirmDialog>

<p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('confirmDelete').show()"/>
```

This blocks Yes button (one with the `id="confirm"`) held by `<p:confirmDialog>`.

The message to be displayed on the confirm dialog is dynamic. It is fetched from the associated backing bean based on certain conditions. Therefore, the dialog is required to be updated before it is displayed.

To update the dialog before it is displayed, the update attribute of `<p:commandButton>` is set as follows.

```
<p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('confirmDelete').show()" update="confirmDeleteDialog"/>
```

This of course, displays a desired message on the dialog dynamically (which is not demonstrated here for the sake of simplicity) but doing so prevents the `<p:blockUI>` from functioning - it does not block the `<p:commandButton>`, if the dialog is updated by it.

Neither errors on the browser console nor exceptions on the server terminal are seen.

What is the way of blocking a button held by a  in addition to displaying a dynamic message on the dialog?

---

**EDIT :-** the answer provided by me is cross-mark.

As noted in the answer given by me, `<p/pe:blockUI>` needs to be updated, when the `<p:commandButton>` held by the confirm dialog is clicked, it takes some time to block the button - `<p:commandButton>` after it is clicked. In the meanwhile, the button can be clicked (either deliberately or  accidently) before the initial request completes that may cause duplicate submits which is certainly against the use of `<p/pe:blockUI>`.

Nothing is preventing a user in my workaround, from clicking the button multiple times before it is blocked by `<p/pe:blockUI>`. Therefore, the answer provided by me is considered to be cross-mark.

Perhaps the way to meet this requirement is completely different.

---

**EDIT 2:-** the actual scenario.

```
//A view scoped bean.
//A list of selected rows in <p:dataTable>.
private List<WishUtils>selectedValues;
//The actual message to be displayed on the dialog.
private String deleteMsg;
//Associated with the rendered property of the "Yes" button on the dialog.
private boolean renderedYesButtonDelete=true;
//The header message/text of the dialog.
private String messageBoxHeader;
//The no button text (its value).
private String noButtonTextDelete="No";

//Getters and setters as required.

public void confirmDelete(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if(selectedValues!=null && !selectedValues.isEmpty()) {
        renderedYesButtonDelete=true;
        noButtonTextDelete="No";
        deleteMsg="A long message about a delete prompt from a resource bundle";
        messageBoxHeader="Confirm Delete";
    } else {
        noButtonTextDelete="OK";
        renderedYesButtonDelete=false;
        deleteMsg="Please select the rows you want to delete";
        messageBoxHeader="Confirm Item Select";
    }
}

public void delete(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if(actionEvent.getComponent().getId().equals("confirmDeleteMultiple")) {
        //Delete the selected rows.
    } else {
        //Notify an error (generally never going to be executed).
    }
}
```

The message box goes here :

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialogDeleteMultiple" widgetVar="confirmDeleteUIWidget" header="#{wishManagedBean.messageBoxHeader}" closeOnEscape="true" appendTo="@(body)" closable="true">
    <p:blockUI id="blockDelete" block="confirmDeleteMultiple" widgetVar="blockDeleteUIWidget"/>
    <p:remoteCommand name="blockDeleteCommand" update="blockDelete" process="@this"/>

    <p:commandButton id="confirmDeleteMultiple" 
                     value="#{messages['confirmdialog.yes']}" 
                     onclick="blockDeleteCommand();" 
                     onstart="PF('blockDeleteUIWidget').show();" 
                     oncomplete="PF('blockDeleteUIWidget').hide();PF('confirmDeleteUIWidget').hide()" 
                     actionListener="#{wishManagedBean.delete}"
                     process="@this"
                     rendered="#{wishManagedBean.renderedYesButtonDelete}"
                     update="a list of components to be updated"/>

    <p:commandButton id="declineDeleteMultiple"
                     value="#{wishManagedBean.noButtonTextDelete}" 
                     onclick="PF('confirmDeleteUIWidget').hide()"
                     type="button"/>

    <f:facet name="message">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputFormat value="#{wishManagedBean.deleteMsg}" escape="false"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<p:blockUI>` indeed fails when the entire dialog is updated. Looks like just another bug. It works when you explicitly call the `PrimeFaces.cw(...)` "create widget" script of the `<p:blockUI>` component (exactly that script which you see in generated HTML output representation of `<p:blockUI>`) on complete of the dialog update.

Given those IDs,

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialogId">
        <p:blockUI id="blockId" ... />
        <p:commandButton id="confirmButtonId" ... />
```

The following `oncomplete` should do it:

```
<p:commandButton update="confirmDialogId" 
    oncomplete="PrimeFaces.cw('BlockUI','blockUI',{id:'formId:blockId',block:'formId:confirmId'});PF('confirmDialogId').show()" />
```

That explains why the `<p:remoteCommand>` trick works as it under the covers basically re-generates the `<p:blockUI>` component along with that `PrimeFaces.cw(...)` call, although it fires an unnecessary ajax request. It might be worth reporting an issue to PrimeFaces guys, telling that `PrimeFaces.cw(...)` of `<p:blockUI>` isn't properly executed when the confirm dialog widget is updated.

Another workaround would be to explicitly ajax-update only the parts you'd like to update instead of the entire dialog. That works for me. The `header` and the `message` attributes of the `<p:confirmDialog>` (and those of many other PrimeFaces components) supports being defined via `<f:facet>` on the attribute name. This allows you to wrap it in a `<h:outputText>` (or `<h:panelGroup>`) so that you can just update it individually. This way you don't need to update the entire dialog and the block UI keeps working as intented.

```
<p:confirmDialog ...>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText id="confirmDeleteDialogHeader" value="#{bean.header}" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="message">
        <h:outputText id="confirmDeleteDialogMessage" value="#{bean.message}" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:panelGroup id="confirmDeleteDialogContent">
        <p:blockUI ... />
        <p:commandButton ... />
        <p:commandButton ... />
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:confirmDialog>

<p:commandButton ... 
    update="confirmDeleteDialogHeader confirmDeleteDialogMessage confirmDeleteDialogContent"
    oncomplete="PF('confirmDelete').show()" />
```

Comment: I trimmed the example to keep it as simple as possible and did not mention everything in the question. In addition to the message on the dialog which can be displayed by using `<f:facet name="message">`, those two "Yes" and "No" buttons and the message header are also determined dynamically. This dialog is used to delete selected rows held by a `<p:dataTable>`, when the given button is pressed. If a user clicks this button without selecting a row/rows then, this dialog only renders one button with the text "OK" with a different text message on the dialog.

Comment: ... If this button is however, clicked after selecting some row/s in the data table then, both the buttons "Yes" and "No" are rendered with a different text message on the dialog. Superficially it appears that it requires a different approach, in this case. Edited the question anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This requires the `<p/pe:blockUI>` to be updated, when the `<p:commandButton>` displayed on the confirm dialog is clicked.

The `<p:blockUI>` can be updated `onclick` using the `<p:remoteCommand>` (`onstart` also works).

The code goes here.

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmDeleteDialog" widgetVar="confirmDelete" message="Message" closeOnEscape="true" appendTo="@(body)" closable="true">
    <p:blockUI id="blockConfirm" block="confirm" widgetVar="blockUI"/>
    <p:remoteCommand name="confirmCommand" update="blockConfirm"/>

    <!--Add PF('confirmDelete').hide() to oncomplete to dismiss the dialog, when this button is clicked.-->
    <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes" onclick="confirmCommand();" onstart="PF('blockUI').show()" oncomplete="PF('blockUI').hide()"/>
    <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" onclick="PF('confirmDelete').hide()" type="button" />                
</p:confirmDialog>

<p:commandButton oncomplete="PF('confirmDelete').show()" update="confirmDeleteDialog" value="Submit"/>
```